# Seach issue with Chinese words

Tags: 8, search, acquia-cloud

I am using these modules:

- https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_solr
- https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_solr_multilingual

Solr is version 4.5.1.

It has issue with Chinese words and partial search.

When the search term is *台湾东部岸外海域 发生5.7级地震*, it works; a partial search for *台湾东部* doesn't work. If there are two words, it will search with the start point of each word; if it takes some of the characters of that word, it fails.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you configure the HMM Chinese Tokenizer/smart Chinese tokenizers in your Solr? The described issue reads to me as if the Chinese phrases aren't correctly broken down into "words" Solr can search for (which isn't a Drupal related issue, but more a question of how to configure Solr for Chinese/CJK languages - you may find better help on stackoverflow & co).

Comment: Hi @mario, as suggested by Acquia we have implemented `<tokenizer class="solr.CJKTokenizerFactory"/>`. Is there any guide to implement `HMM Chinese Tokenizer/smart Chinese tokenizers`?

Comment: We unfortunately aren't using Acquia solutions. Best Acquia related suggestion I found is this one: https://support.acquia.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004454973-CJK-Chinese-Japanese-and-Korean-Language-support-and-Acquia-Search - Our Chinese supporting search servers are self hosted and heavily customized by our search experts. I can't be of a great help here. There are plenty examples in the net that address the setup for more recent versions of Solr. If you are going to use your own Solr server, they might be of help.

Comment: Thanks @MarioSteinitz for your valuable comments